# How do I typeset multiple additions nicely?

Tags: math-mode, arrays, calculations, xlop

For some project, I'm trying to typeset something into approximately this:

```
 1234
  321
12345
    6
----- + 
13906
```

I've seen people do this using `xlop` for the addition of two values, which works really nicely, and `array` for more values, which is not ideal.

Is there any convenient package that can (something like) this for multiple values?

Comment: do you want something different than the layout you'd get from a simple `array` ?

Comment: Not neccessarily, but if you look up the `xlop` package you'll see that its syntax for specifying the addition is rather consice, as opposed to the very verbose `array`. I was hoping a multi-value variant of `xlop`, or at least a less repetitive version of `array` existed.

Comment: related questions http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45304/vertical-addition-and-multiplication-and-long-division and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11702/how-to-present-a-vertical-multiplication-addition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer does not provide additional spacing between digits, as is done with `xlop`, but otherwise provides multi-addend addition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage{stringstrings,stackengine}
%%% \showsum based on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219090/
%%%            writing-manual-summation-of-two-numbers/219113#219113
\newcounter{mysum}
\newcommand\showsum[1]{%
  \convertchar[q]{#1}{ }{+}%
  \setcounter{mysum}{\numexpr\thestring\relax}%
  \def\stackalignment{r}%
  \edef\tmp{\themysum}%
  {\stackunder{\underline{\ \Longstack{#1}}}{%
   \tmp}\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{\,+}}%
}
\begin{document}
\opadd{12}{12}

\showsum{1 2 3 4}  $\qquad$
\showsum{23 567 34 32}  $\qquad$
\showsum{1 3567 2334 3352 567}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks wonderful. Not as simple as a using a package, but very clear and looks beautiful. I will definitely be using this. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addition}{O{c}m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_bert_addition_seq { + } { #2 }
  \begin{array}[#1]{@{}r@{\;}l}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_bert_addition_seq { \\ } \\[-.5ex]
  \additionrule \\[-.5ex]
  \int_eval:n { #2 }
  \end{array}
 }
\seq_new:N \l_bert_addition_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\additionrule}{%
  \leaders\hrule height \dimexpr \fontdimen22\textfont2+0.2pt\relax
                 depth \dimexpr -\fontdimen22\textfont2+0.2pt\relax
  \hfill\hspace*{0pt} & +
}

\begin{document}

\[
\addition{1234+321+12345+6}
\]

\end{document}
```

The optional argument to `\addition` can be `t`, `b` or `c` and is passed to `array`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since I can't comment on this (not enough reputation) I'll post this as an answer. Do you have to do it inside a math-environment? You could accomplish that in a tabular-environment easily I think.

EDIT: Because it was requested:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{rr}
         &1234\\
        +&321\\
        +&12345\\
        +&6\\
        \hline
        &13906
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Please note that this doesn't calculate the results. Also please note that this puts a '+' in front of every row and not next to the \hline. For that use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{rr}
         1234 & \\
          321 & \\
        12345 & \\
            6 & \multirow{2}{*}{+}\\
        \cline{1-1}
        13906 & \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, provide an example how to do this ..., than this comment will become answer :-)