# 3 column math questions

Tags: columns

[image]

Help! I am a primary teacher and I am trying to make 3 columns of questions like this one! I have figured out how to write a 1 column but I need to replicate this with 3 columns in total.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309961/pencil-and-paper-subtraction-in-latex, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213357/addition-with-3-elements-using-xlop, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11702/how-to-present-a-vertical-multiplication-addition (still looking for more...)

Comment: You should take a look at the `tasks` package: it's designed for this sort of things.

Answer (score 2):

I am all for encouraging the use of LaTeX in schools, so here is one way of solving your problem -- even though you have not given a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show what you have tried:)

I would use the `multicol` package together with a little macro for typesetting each problem:

[image]

Here is the latex code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{multicol}
% Usage: \Problem{n}{operation}{m}
\newcommand\Problem[3]{$\begin{array}[t]{r}#1\\#2#3\\\hline\quad\end{array}$}

\begin{document}

  \begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
      \item \Problem{8}-{6}
      \item \Problem{40}+{39}
      \item \Problem{56}-{23}
      \item \Problem{87}-{54}
      \item \Problem{35}+{72}
      \item \Problem{59}-{3}
      \item \Problem{37}-{32}
      \item \Problem{13}-{4}
      \item \Problem{3}\times{3}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

The `multicols` environment puts everything into three columns. If, instead, you wanted two columns then you could change `\begin{multicols}{3}` to `\begin{multicols}{2}`. I am using the `enumitem` package to set the labels to the ones you have in your post (this is done by the `label=\arabic*)` after the `\begin{enumerate}`. This is overkill but I like `enumitem`.

Finally, the `\Problem` macro is used to typeset the problem. It takes three arguments, `n`, the operation and `m` and then creates a one column array to "draw" the corresponding problem. Using the macro makes it much easier to typeset and proof-read your questions.

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME! I am not by any means someone who seriously knows how to do this....I teach Kindergarten and am doing research on Spatial reasoning.... I am trying to put this sheet together digitally and discovered this as the best alternative-however there is a learning curve. I am grateful!

Comment: @RuthieSloan Glad to help:) There is a learning curve...but once you get there it will save you time.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

No laughing....I have been trouble shooting and sifting through Q&A to try this!